# Forms Authentication fails to redirect to Login

Tags: iis, web-config, forms-authentication

I am developing a WebForms project in VS 2017 and I would like to add Forms Authentication so that anonymous users cannot access a specific page (called Resources). So far, my Login page is logging in users as it should, authenticated users have access to Resources, and all users can browse my non-protected pages.

**Here's my problem:** Whenever an anonymous user attempts to access Resources, a server error occurs instead of being redirected to the Login page. In IIS Express the error message is *"HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized. You do not have permission to view this directory or page"*. In Local IIS it says *"Error message 401.2: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.*

I believe the browser and server are trying to authenticate using different methods, but I can't figure out how to fix this.

In IIS manager, I've enabled both forms and anonymous authentication and disabled the other methods for my website. For anonymous auth, I've tried setting the user to IUSR as well as Application pool identity while running on DefaultAppPool with full security permissions - neither worked. And for Forms auth, the parameters match my web.config file, aka same name and login url (not sure if that matters).

Here is the authentication and authorization code in my web.config:

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" defaultUrl="Index.aspx" loginUrl="Login.aspx" />
  </authentication>
</system.web>
<location path="Resources.aspx">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Am I missing something obvious? Are there other settings I should check out? Any help is immensely appreciated!

Comment: Forgot to mention I am using IIS 8.5